# Angular ng-repeat filter/search by formatted date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a list of date objects which I want to display like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="myDate in myDates | filter:dateFilter">{{myDate | date:'dd. MMMM yyyy'}}</div>
```

The dateFilter is bound to an input field.

Now the Problem is, when I type in "October" for example, no date is found because angular seems to be looking only into the date object which looks like this:

```
Thu Oct 27 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
```

Is it possible to also search in the formatted date string "27. October 2009"?

Comment: u can store all the dates inside an array by applying  `| date:'dd. MMMM yyyy'` and using custom filter u can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own filter function, which is quite easy to do: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

That way you'll be able to implement any custom filtering logic you'd like to have.